# React TS. Объединить 2 и более компоненты выполняющую одну и ту же задачу (но типы даных и параметры разные) в одну универсальную

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, typescript, типы-данных

React TS.
Объединить 2 и более компоненты выполняющую одну и ту же задачу (но типы даных и параметры разные) в одну универсальную.

Подброно:
Нужно декомпозировать компоненты в 1. Но проблема в том, что `list` из `store` имеет разные данные, функции (там есть и общие но у них тоже разные типы и параметры  ) и тип данных в 1-ой это `quiz.list` с `IQuizRow[]` , а во 2-ой это `quiz_session.list` с типом `IQuizSessionRow[]`.

Но по сути эти компоненты выполняют один алгоритм. Отображают список.

Пробовал в `props` прокидывать `list: any[]` и `store: any`. Но тогда это немного не правильно с точки зрения TS. нужно чтобы точно знал что есть в props.

Также не подходит вариант с общим типом который будет равен типам props. так так придется каждый раз добавлять туда новый тип если нужен новый список
с другими данными, и если  там будет 2+ типов это по сути тот же `any` так что опять нарушаем принцип TS.

1. Это список викторин

```
const QiuzList = observer(() => {
    const {store} = useContext(Context);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {height} = useWindowSize()

    useEffect(() => {
        store.quiz.list.loader.set(true)
        return () => store.quiz.list.loader.set(true)
    }, [])

    const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(5);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0);

    const [list, setList] = useState<IQuizRow[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reload()
    }, [offset])

    const reload = () => {
        store.quiz.list.request({limit, offset}).then(r => {
            console.log(r)
            setList([...list, ...store.quiz.list.get().results])
        })
    }

    return <div>...</div>
});
```

2. Это список сессий

```js
const QiuzSessionList = observer(() => {
    const {store} = useContext(Context);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const {height} = useWindowSize()

    useEffect(() => {
        store.quiz_session.list.loader.set(true)
        return () => store.quiz_session.list.loader.set(true)
    }, [])

    const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(5);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0);

    const [list, setList] = useState<IQuizSessionRow[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reload()
    }, [offset])

    const reload = () => {
        store.quiz_session.list.request({limit, offset}).then(r => {
            console.log(r)
            setList([...list, ...store.quiz_session.list.get().results])
        })
    }

    return <div>...</div>

})
```

Какая же мне нужна компонента примерно. Дальше псевдокод:

```
type Props = {
    props_list: ТИП КОТОРЫЙ РАВЕН YOUR_LIST_STORE из store со всеми достпуными в ней функциями,
    row: YOUR_LIST_ROW_TYPE,
}

const List = observer(({props_list, row}:Props) => {
    const {store} = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
        // вот тут я вроде вызываю функции,
        // но я точно не могу быть уверен,
        // что такая функия есть. так как type any
        props_list.loader.set(true)
        return () => props_list.loader.set(true)
    }, [])

    const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(5);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0);

    const [virtual_list, setVirtualList] = useState<YOUR_LIST_ROW_TYPE[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reload()
    }, [offset])

    const reload = () => {
        // вот тут я вроде вызываю функции, 
        // но я точно не могу быть уверен,
        // что такая функия есть. так как type any
        props_list.request({limit, offset}).then(r => {
            console.log(r)
            setVirtualList([...virtual_list, ...props_list.get().results])
        })
    }

    return <div>...</div>

})
```

Вот так не подойдет с `any` т.к могут быть ошибки в реалтайме
и опять же, нужно, чтобы не было возможности вызывать любые функции:

```
type Props = {
    props_list: any,
    row: any,
}

const List = observer(({props_list, row}:Props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props_list.loader.set(true)
        return () => props_list.loader.set(true)
    }, [])

    const [limit, setLimit] = useState<number>(5);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0);

    const [virtual_list, setVirtualList] = useState<typeof row[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reload()
    }, [offset])

    const reload = () => {
        props_list.request({limit, offset}).then((r: any) => {
            console.log(r)
            setVirtualList([...virtual_list, ...props_list.get().results])
        })
    }

    return <div>...</div>

})
```

Comment: Картинки замените кодом. Если надо внести исправление в вопрос, можно воспользоваться кнопкой "править"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Все, вроде. Расписал красочно и подробно )

Comment: Боюсь так не выйдет. Объеденять универсально любые типы и так, что бы они не были any[]. Тут либо перечисление(можно отдельный тип выделить и там вести перечисление типов), либо никак.